# How to connect ubuntu inside Virtualbox using Bitvise ssh client?

Tags: ubuntu

So I am using windows10 laptop, there I run virtualbox and Bitvise ssh client program.

And in virtualbox, running ubuntu 16.04 vm.

Now, how to connect through Bitvise to this ubuntu vm?

I set network setting at VB like [Bridge to adapter] and VM's connection info says IP address is 192.168.0.20

So I write at Bitvise like 192.168.0.20 and port 22, but failed to connect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi have you installed and started sshd daemon at Ubuntu VM?

if so, you should get something like:

```
linux-vm$ sudo systemctl status sshd
● ssh.service - OpenBSD Secure Shell server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/ssh.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since mar 2018-03-06 09:29:42 GMT; 3h 20min ago
  Process: 1765 ExecReload=/bin/kill -HUP $MAINPID (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 1557 (sshd)
   CGroup: /system.slice/ssh.service
           └─1557 /usr/sbin/sshd -D
```

if you don't see this, then probably you will need to install it:

```
sudo apt-get install ssh
```

as I'm not sure Ubuntu install and enable this by default...